# sendto() fails, cuts telnet connection and blocks program

Tags: c, udp, telnet, blocking, errno

I've been stuck with this problem for days and I really cannot figure out where this comes from.

I'm doing a program communicating through UDP. I'm using the `sendto()` method to communicate between programs. Also, there is a UI TCP socket opened and used by the user, managing the program through telnet. The telnet part is 100% working with other features of the program.

The problem is, when I'm using the `sendto()` method, the program blocks totally and the Telnet connection is broken (Communication has been cut by host, it says). My problem is that, as the program blocks, I cannot figure out why `sendto()` is failing because it wont execute what is after. Even with something like :

```
if(sendto(...)<0)
{
    perror("Sendto error :");
}
```

nothing happens, I cannot get any information with `errno`. The fact that the telnet connection is broken seems weird to me because it is on a very different port and therefore shouldn't be interrupted like this. 
I tried to set my UDP socket as non blocking but it still doesn't work. Here is the non working part of the code :

```
struct sockaddr_in address;

hp = gethostbyname(myaddr);

address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(udp_port);

memcpy(&(address.sin_addr.s_addr), hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);

sendto(fd, buffer, buffer_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

close(fd);
```

Thanks in advance for your help and ask me if you want more specific informations.

Comment: Can you try to print right before `sendto` and right after ? It shouldn't block. I suspect `gethostbyname` is causing it.

Comment: Yeah, that's how i figured out sendto was the reason : the printing right before works but not the following. I also tried with an alternative to gethostbyname but it didn't work ...

Comment: Wow, finally found the problem ... My file descriptor was done with a wrong function (it was called UDP but was creating a TCP ...) Thanks for your help anyways :)